# Excel, buscar palabras en una celda y añadir excepciones

Tags: excel, excepciones, formulas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Buenas a todos,
Estoy usando una fórmula para buscar palabras específicas en una celda y que me marque una X si la encuentra y si no, que me deje la celda vacía. Ahora.. como se ve en las imágenes, es posible poner condiciones? Por ejemplo: en la lista de ingredientes tengo leche de coco, que no es un alergeno, sin embargo la leche si. Habria la posibilidad de buscar “leche” como alergeno pero “leche de coco” como excepción? 
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Tendrías que identificar de alguna manera la palabra `Milk` de manera exclusiva. No conozco tus datos, pero quizás sería mejor que buscase `Milk,` es decir, con 1 coma al final. Esto ayudaría que detectase la palabra Milk sola, por su cuenta.Pero ojo, porque si Milk es el único ingrediente  o el último, no te serviría al no tener coma. Otra opción separarte tus ingredientes en columnas con la utilidad de Texto en Columnas, aunque quizás sea más engorroso. Excepciones como tal, lo veo más complicado, la verdad, salvo que te diseñes algún código en VBA.

Comment: Gracias Elier, he hecho algo parecido a lo que has dicho.